# how to save many plots on a Shiny screen to the same png file

Tags: r, ggplot2, save, shiny, png

[image]Attached is a screenshot of a Shiny application dashboard that I have created.  Actually these are 6 ggplot2 plots side by side.  How do I save them to the same png file? for convenient printing and pasting into other applications?

Comment: have a look at this : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We switched from ggplot2 to plotly for this and created sub-plots.  Plotly is smart enough to print the entire plot.